# Optimizing a .txt extraction function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to optimize a function to import .txt files for data analysis. I have a somewhat large corpus, but given that the function only reads the documents and creates the Data Frame with each paragraph as an element I think it is taking WAY too long, around 30min for 17 documents with about 1000 pages each.

Any suggestions on how to make this faster? I only have to load it once, but it's annoying to loose half an hour to load the data.

```
def read_docs_paragraph(textfolder):
"""
This function reads all the files in a folder and returns a dataframe with the content of the files chunked by paragraphs
(if .txt file is organized by paragraphs) and the name of the file.

Parameters
----------
textfolder : str
    The path of the folder where the files are located.
    
Returns
-------
df : DataFrame
    A dataframe with the content of the files and the name of the file.
"""

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Corpus'] = ''
df['Estado'] = ''

#Iterate
for filename in os.listdir(textfolder):
    #Opens the file you specified
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                df_length = len(df)
                df.loc[df_length] = line
                df['Estado'].loc[df_length] = filename
return df
```

Comment: Please provide some well chosen sample of your text file. Anyway, you are iterating on the content character by character. Wherever you found the model for this piece of code, well, never use it again!

Comment: For each *character* you add a row to the dataframe. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Wrong function, the one taking 100 years is the one extracting paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion with [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) and [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html), both from the standard library:

```
from pathlib import Path
import fileinput

def read_docs_paragraph(textfolder):
    with fileinput.input(Path(textfolder).glob("*.txt")) as files:
        return pd.DataFrame(
            ([line, files.filename()] for line in files),
            columns = ["Corpus", "Estado"]
        )
```

I've timed it a bit and it seems like 700 times faster (that might depend on the files, machine, etc., though).

As pointed out by @FranciscoMelloCastro: If you have to be explicit about the encoding you could use `openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("utf-8")`, or starting with Python 3.10 `encoding="utf-8"`.

Comment: WOW this worked. Just one thing for anyone hoping to use this solution, you might need to pass "openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("utf-8")" as an argument in fileinput.input()

Thanks mate, you just save me a whole bunch of hours

Comment: @FranciscoMelloCastro Thanks for the feedback: You're right, I skipped that out of habit because I usually don't have to be explicit about the encoding. I'll put it in the answer.

Comment: BTW, this reduced the loading time from 30min to 0.5s in my machine